# How to find the intersection

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am supposed to find the intersection of :
$$\begin{cases} 2^{x}=y \\ 31x+8y-94=0 \end{cases}$$ 
When I substitute the first equation into the second one:
$$\frac{94-31x}{8}=2^{x}$$ and I do not know how to continue.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\dfrac{94-31x}{8}=2^x \\ 94-31x=8(2^x) \\ 8(2^x)+31x-94=0$$
As $8(2^x)+31x-94$ is strictly increasing, there is only one answer. Then we can try to find the answer by testing.

When $x=0$, $8(2^x)+31x-94=-86<0$

When $x=1$, $8(2^x)+31x-94=-47<0$

When $x=2$, $8(2^x)+31x-94=0$

Therefore $x=2$ is the only answer. The intersection point is at $(2,2^2)=(2,4)$

Comment: Okay, thanks I thought that there is some step by step solution

Answer (score 3):

$$\dfrac{94-31x}{8}=2^x$$

is correct, you might proceed like this: It is $8=2^3$ and we get:

$$94-31x=2^{x+3}$$

Note that the RHS is always positive, while the LHS is negative when $x>3$, so there are not many values of $x$ to check.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "there are not many values of $x$ to check."

Comment: @Teepeemm I assume that x is supposed to be an integer. Since there can not exist a solution for $x<3$ we have that $x\in\{0,1,2\}$. For negative $x$ the RHS is a fraction. The LHS is not. So there are just 3 possible values for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $x$ can only be $2$, $2$ solves the equation.

Comment: Thank you I got it

Comment: Nice that i could help you!

Comment: Is Shelley your real name? A nice one.

Comment: yes, it is, thanks